# How to post ibeacon information to server

Tags: mysql, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, ibeacon

I am in the process of prototyping and app (Cordova/phonegap).

I want to know if its possible to have ibeacon information, like (UDID, Major, Minor, Signal Strength) retrieved from my app and then posted from the app to a MySQL database.

Let's say the ibeacon broadcast every 5 seconds then I want all data mentioned above posted to the database.

If it's possible is there a script that can be used as an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible and a very common use case.  Using a [Cordova plugin for beacon detection](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon), you will get callbacks every second with a list of all beacons seen.

How you make a server call in JavaScript is nothing special about beacons.  One way with jQuery is:

```
$.post('/remote-url', {json: jsonString });
```

The main thing you need to understand is that you probably can't make a call to the server every second.  You need to throttle the calls so you only make one every 15-30 seconds or so to keep the requests from piling up.